# How to capture deeplink when app is open in background?

Tags: firebase, xamarin.forms, deep-linking, firebase-dynamic-links

Hi I am working on a xamarin project and dynamic link is implemented in this project. I am clicking on dynamic link and able to extract parameters from it when my app is closed, I am doing the same by this way :

For Android

```
public void CheckForDynamicLinkParameter()
        {
            var deepLink = AppInviteReferral.GetDeepLink(Intent);

            //Extracting page to be opened from deepLink URL
            SetPageFromLink(deepLink);

            var data = Intent.Data;

            if (deepLink != null)
            {

                Uri myUri = new Uri(deepLink);

                string param1 = HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(myUri.Query).Get("id");
                string param2 = HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(myUri.Query).Get("token");
                Utilities.Configuration.UpdateConfigValue(Utilities.Constants.deepLinkEmail, param1);
                Utilities.Configuration.UpdateConfigValue(Utilities.Constants.deepLinkToken, param2);

            }


        }
```

CheckForDynamicLinkParameter() method I am calling in OnCreate() of main activity and extracting params from deeplink and navigating to some different pages.

Samae way in iOS I am calling ContinueUserActivity(). This way I am able to find parameters only when my app is closed.

My issue is that, when I am clicking the dynamic link when app is open/in backgrounsd I am unable to capture the deeplink. So is there any way to capture deeplink when myt app is open ?

Comment: Is there any problem in using OnResume()? Of if the LaunchMode is SingleTop or similar, then NewIntent()

Comment: @AdamPedley Thanks for the update. I tried putting my code in OnResume(), its hitting there but i don't know why var deepLink = AppInviteReferral.GetDeepLink(Intent); 
the above code returns deeplink as null.

Comment: Does the Intent variable have the same values, as when its called from OnCreate?